# Swift not passing the correct variable value

Tags: json, xcode, swift

Ok, I am new to Swift, and I am having an issue with passing a variable in the URL.
The idea is to click on the button, pass the product id, and on the next view controller to display the information relating to the particular product id.

It keeps passing the last id in the array, not the one I clicked on.

I have used print(product_id_as) to see if the id's are being retrieved correctly, and there's no problem there.

I am using a table view to display JSON data from an external database.
This is the code I am using to display the data.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.product.text = maindata["product"] as? String
    product_id = (maindata["id"] as? String)!
    product_id_as = Int(product_id)!
    buttonTitle = (maindata["product_id"] as? String)!
    cell.testButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal)

    func renewQuestions(sender : UIButton) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://initiateaustralia.com.au/initiate/vq.php?product=\(product_id_as))")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why is there an unused function in your function?

Comment: product_id and product_id_as seem to be variables declared in your class outside this method. So, perhaps they are modified by other methods. Try to declare them locally inside the method and see if it changes something

Comment: How are you navigating to the next VC. Post that code also. and whats that renewQuestions func doing inside cellForRow...

Comment: @ArunGupta its inside the cellForRow because i thought this might have been causing the issue. But thats not the case.

Comment: @EricD how do i use that function? I cant use it outside of the tableView function (because the variables are declared inside the function), so i cant use it as a IBAction, which is how i normally would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a selector to your button and assign indexPath.row as buttons tag. RenewQuestions will be the selector of your button. We will be moving that out and using tag we will extract the data on button click

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell 
let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
cell.product.text = maindata["product"] as? String
product_id = (maindata["id"] as? String)! 
product_id_as = Int(product_id)!  
buttonTitle = (maindata["product_id"] as? String)!  
cell.testButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal) 
cell.testButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.renewQuestions(_:)), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.testButton.tag = indexPath.row
return cell; 
}


func renewQuestions(sender : UIButton) {
 let selectedItem = sender.tag
let selectedData = values[selectedItem]
let selectedProduct_id = (selectedData["id"] as? String)! 
let selectedProduct_id_as = Int(selectedProduct_id)! 
let url = NSURL(string: "http://initiateaustralia.com.au/initiate/vq.php?product=\(selectedProduct_id_as))")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray 
}
```

Now perform your segue to next view control.